# Adding navigation buttons to modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

Ive already made my sign in modal, however im trying to add buttons to the top, one button navigating to register/sign up, and the other button leading to the sign in modal, as represented by the picture i added here.[Picture of sign in modal. (i recommend you look at it to better clarify what I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88QAn.jpg)

I went on the official bootstrap docs, however i do not see anything about adding nav buttons to my modal.

If anyone has any tips/ code i could try, please let me know. thanks in advance! (I posted the HTML code and CSS code below.)

```
<!-- Sign Up Modal -->
<div class="modal fade signup-modal" id="signupModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="Sign Up" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content rounded-4 signup-modal-background">
      <div class="modal-header p-5 pt-4 pb-0 border-bottom-0">
        <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="modal-header p-5 pt-0 pb-0 border-bottom-0 end-50">
        <h2 class="fw-bold mb-0 fs-2 text-center">Register your Account</h2>
      </div>
       <div class="modal-header p-5 pb-0 pt-1 border-bottom-0">
        <h5 class="fw-normal mb-0 text-center">Lets get started with your account</h5>
      </div>
      <hr>
       <div class="modal-body p-5 pt-0 pb-0">
        <form class="">
          <div class="form-floating mb-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control rounded-3 cbs-form input-group-custom-field" id="usernameInput" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="on" required>
            <label for="usernameInput">Username</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-floating mb-3">
            <input type="email" class="form-control rounded-3 cbs-form input-group-custom-field" id="emailInput" placeholder="name@example.com" autocomplete="on" required>
            <label for="emailInput">Email address</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-floating mb-3">
            <input type="password" class="form-control rounded-3 cbs-form input-group-custom-field" id="passwordInput" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="on" required>
            <label for="passwordInput">Password</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-floating mb-3">
            <input type="password" class="form-control rounded-3 cbs-form input-group-custom-field" id="confirmPasswordInput" placeholder="Password-Confirm" autocomplete="on" required>
            <label for="confirmPasswordInput">Confirm Password</label>
          </div>
          <input class="" type="checkbox" id="agreementCheckbox" name="Agreement Checkbox" required>
          <label class="text-center d-inline" for="agreementCheckbox"><span>I agree to the <a class="gray text-links tooltip-test" title="Terms and Conditions" href="https://www.termsfeed.com/live/7f2a7964-ad07-4450-9cc5-b4435160db61">Terms and Conditions</a> and <a class="gray text-links tooltip-test" title="Privacy Policy" href="https://www.termsfeed.com/live/51c49715-5a49-477f-aa7b-d431b74dde6c">Privacy Policy</a></span></label>
          <button class="w-100 mb-2 mt-2 btn btn-lg rounded-3 btn btn1" type="submit">Next</button>
          <div class="text-center">
                    <p>Already have an account?<a title="Sign In" href="login.php" class="gray text-links">
                        Sign In
                      </a>
                    </p>
                  </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer p-5 pt-1 pb-2">
      <h2 class="fs-5 fw-bold mb-3 text-center pb-0">Use a third-party to create your account.</h2>
          <button class="w-100 py-2 mb-2 btn rounded-3 border google-signup" type="submit">
            Continue with Google
          </button>
          <button class="w-100 py-2 mb-2 btn rounded-3 border google-signup" type="submit">
            Continue with Google
          </button>
          <button class="w-100 py-2 mb-2 btn rounded-3 border google-signup" type="submit">
            Continue with Google
          </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


/* Sign up Modal */
.signup-modal-background {
background-color: #222022;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [button-group](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/button-group/#basic-example) for that. Please add below button-group link code in your modal header.

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary active" aria-current="page">Register</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn btn-outline-primary">Sign In</a>
</div>
```